# How to generate php files on server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, filenames, friendly-url, pretty-urls

I have a flash game site, which has a play.php file, which gets the game's name by `$_GET` like

```
http://host/play.php?game=free-kick-puzzle
```

which works nicely but I think it's not so good for google bot etc. And I see that many other sites do it like

```
host/games/free-kick-puzzle.php
```

So is there any way to "generate" this `gamename.php` file automatically?
Thanks !

Comment: You're looking for a routing engine.

Comment: Pretty URLs and `.htaccess` rules?

Comment: Using htaccess: Mod_rewrite

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to "generate" files on the server, you just want to create nicer URLs that map to the ugly ones behind the scenes. One way to do that is by using rewrite rules.

Using an Apache module called [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you can make URLs more SEO friendly with directives you write in your `.htaccess` file.

In your `.htaccess` file, you could use code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)/?$ /play.php?game=$1
```

This is just an example, and there are many other options available when using rewrite rules. I highly recommend looking at the documentation in the [Apache docs about mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

In this example, you're finding anything after `games/`, represented by the parenthesis and the RegEx in between them. The `/?` means the trailing slash is optional. After the `$` is what you actually want to serve to the visitor. The `$1` is where whatever is found in between the parenthesis is placed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need a little more help, I couldn't find .htaccess neither in wampserver, nor in my webhost. Should I create one that only contains the two lines that you wrote? will that work?

Comment: Yes, create an `.htaccess` file if it doesn't already exist in the root of your web host.